# What is the need of finally block when we can close files and all in catch block

Tags: java, exception, try-catch-finally

What is the need of `finally` block when we can close files and all in `catch` block.
Whatever thing we are closing or clearing in `finally` block can it be done in `catch` block. Please tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: Read Exception hierarchy and try catch carefully and study special cases , will help

Answer (score 6):

You normally want to perform the same clean-up action whether an exception is thrown or not. Doing that *just* with catch blocks is painful - especially if you want to make sure that you only call `close()` once, even if *that* throws. You'd end up with:

```
bool closeCalled = false;
OutputStream stream = ...;
try {
   stream.write(...);
   closeCalled = true;
   stream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
   if (!closeCalled) {
       // TODO: Add another try/catch here? What do we want to
       // do if this throws?
       stream.close();
   }
   throw e;
}
```

Compare that with:

```
OutputStream = ...;
try {
   stream.write(...);
} finally {
   // TODO: Still need to work out what to do if this throws.
   stream.close();
}
```

Or best:

```
try (OutputStream stream = ...) {
    stream.write(...);
}
```

Personally, I think the last example is by far the cleanest - do you *really* want the first block of code everywhere? Oh, and this is a simple case - we're only catching a single exception. Imagine repeating that code in each `catch` clause, and if there are multiple ways of exiting the `try` block, repeating the close call for each of those, too... ick.

Additionally, as pointed out by Nicolas in comments, there are all those unchecked exceptions which you *don't* catch (and which can be painful to catch and rethrow). Fundamentally, the principle of "I just want to clean up my resources whatever happens" is very, very compelling...

Comment: @NicolasFilotto: That's true, you'd have to catch `Throwable` everywhere and rethrow in nasty ways. Will add that in. Although even if that *weren't* a problem, I'd still want try/finally...

Comment: Thanks Jon for your help

Comment: Even if one doesn't want to perform *exactly* the same cleanup actions in exception/non-exception cases, being able to perform the common parts in a `finally` block is helpful; the try-with-resources will even take care of some aspects of that automatically (e.g. if the main-line code succeeds, but cleanup throws an exception, it will propagate the exception from the cleanup; if the mainline throws an exception and the cleanup does too, try-with-resources will propagate the mainline's exception while attaching the suppressed exception from the cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the need of finally block when we can close files and all in catch block. whatever thing we are closing or clearing in the finally block can it be done inn catch block

`catch` block will be executed only when an Exception arises in the `try` block.

When you want to do some operations every time like Clean up  , You need to write the code in `finally` block.

Finally will be executed always and catch block will not executed always.

Consider the below example ,

you opened a file and try to copy to another file in the `try` block, If code executes fine , catch block will not be executed  and you ending on not closing the file

Comment: I got it thanks a lot to all.

Comment: What is the problem if I close the file without using any 'finally' block ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed: The OP wanted to close the files in the catch block and it is answered. It is fine to close the block in any executable code. But finally, block will be executed every time.